# Can't request data with web client from parse server

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server

I have an iOS app and a javascript web client. The iOS app is working as expected but with the web client I always get this error message:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
{"error":"unauthorized"}

As a server I use the parse-server example deployed to heroku. [git repo](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server.git)

My config is this:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://heroku_q21****.mlab.com:11382/heroku_q2***',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || '****',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '***', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://****.herokuapp.com/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  //javascriptKey: process.env.JAVASCRIPT_KEY || '***', 
  verbose : process.env.VERBOSE || 1,
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["GameScore", "Player"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

It does not matter if I use javascriptKey or not. Same result.
As web client I use the test.html of the repo to make simple parse tests.
Can someone tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: Your credentials are wrong.

Comment: what you mean? the *** ? Are you joking? They are just a mask, I don't want to tell everyone my credentials

Comment: No I'm not joking. You need to go check your credentials.